# Reference Doxygen Class or Namespace list from \mainpage

Tags: c++, doxygen

We have our own \mainpage section defined for our Doxygen build and I want to have a link as part of this to the auto-generated Class Index page (classes.html) and Namespace List top level page (namespaces.html).

I've tried things like \ref namespaces and \ref classes but that doesn't work. Any idea what the magic tag is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no symbolic names at the moment to refer to the overview pages.
If it is for HTML only you can do

```
<a href="classes.html">Link to the class index</a>
```

If you need something for other output formats as well, you can wrap the above in `\htmlonly`...`\endhtmlonly` and do something similar for the other output formats.